# Holomorphic deformation of complex structure on the real plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, complex-manifolds

It is known that each complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is biholomorphic to either $\mathbb{C}$ or the open unit disk $\Delta$.

One can continuously deform one complex structure to the other as is for example done in [Winkelmann - Deformations of Riemann surfaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7086) (page 3).

My question is

> Can this deformation be taken to be holomorphic on the deformation parameter? That is, does there exist a non-trivial complex analytic family $M \to D$ where $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a small disk, the central fiber is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, and the generic fiber is biholomorphic to $\Delta$?

Note that all the theorems that assure complex analytic triviality of deformations when $H^1(X,TX)$ vanishes, use the hypothesis that $X$ is compact.

Comment: How about $M=\{|z w|<1 \}\subset D\times \mathbb{C}$ with projection to the first coordinate?

Comment: Beautiful! I think it works. If you write it in an answer with a small argument it will be the accepted solution

Answer (score 7):

The answer is no. This follows from the so-called $\lambda$-lemma of Sullivan, Mane Sad and Lyubich: Let $D$ be a disk, $C$ the complex plane and $A$ any set in C.
Let $f:D\times A\to C$ be a function with the following properties:

1. $\lambda\mapsto f(\lambda,z)$ is holomorphic for every $z\in A$.
2. $z\mapsto f(\lambda,z)$ is injective for every $\lambda\in D$,
3. $z\mapsto f(0,z)=z$ for every $z\in A$.

Then for every $\lambda\in D$ the map $z\mapsto f(\lambda,z)$ is quasisymmetric (=quasiconformal if $A$ is open)

Since the plane is not conformally equivalent to a disk, this implies that the
answer to your question is negative.

Ref. MR0732343 
Mañé, R.; Sad, P.; Sullivan, D.,
On the dynamics of rational maps,
Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup. (4) 16 (1983), no. 2, 193–217.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to apply your answer to my situation. You are looking at my $D$ to be embedded in _your_ C? And then my family $M$ would be your product? Observe that my central fiber is not a disk by hypothesis. Also the conclusion of the $\lambda$-lemma is that the map admits a quasiconformal _extension_

Comment: Your map $f$ is my family $M \to D$ ?

Comment: $1$ is not satisfied in my situation.

Comment: I probably misunderstood what is a "complex analytic family". Can you define it? On my opinion "a deformation depending on a complex analytic parameter" is exactly what satisfies 1,2,3.

Comment: In this context, the simplest definition that fits is: a complex analytic family of complex manifolds is the triple $(M,D,\pi)$ where $\pi:M \to D$ is a flat holomorphic submersion which is a $C^\infty$ locally trivial (and hence trivial) fibration. The usual context is that of analytic families of _compact_ manifolds (in this case you only ask that $\pi$ is a holomorphic proper submersion). The case where fibers are open is much more subtle and less studied. By definition, the fibers are all diffeomorphic but not neccesarily biholomorphic.

Comment: But then you have a trivial example (in the comments).

Comment: What does that mean? That it was my fault that your answer is wrong because my question was too easy? I don’t mind admitting that my question was “trivial” (whatever that means) or that I didn’t know something (that I learned today) or that I’m more ignorant than a lot of people. I asked this question because I am no expert and I’m learning deformation theory on my own with no experts around me.

Comment: @Paul: "What does it mean?" That you have now two answers, depending on what is meant by a "deformation". And you can choose the one that you need.  Nothing more.

Comment: I still don’t know what is your possible definition of complex analytic family of complex structures. My definition agrees with your notion of “family of deformations deepending on a complex parameter”. What is your f,D,A,C in terms of my $M \to D$? Where is your central fiber biholomorphic to C and your generic fiber biholomorphic to $\Delta$ in order to arrive to a contradiction?

Comment: Take $A=C$, for example. Then no other fiber can be a disk.

Comment: and what is the map f? The projection onto the first factor or the second factor? Again, what is f, D,A,C in terms of my M, arrow and D? (So that I can try to apply the lemma)

Comment: $f$ is what I would call "a deformation". But I do not insist. I just stated a theorem. You decide whether it is useful for you or not.

Comment: But you claimed that your theorem implies that the answer to my question is no. I say that I don’t know how to apply your theorem to my situation so I need to know what are your letters and maps in terms of my letters and maps.

Comment: My $f(\lambda,z)$ is what Winkler denotes by $\phi_t(z)$ on p. 3 of the paper you cite, my $\lambda$ is his $t$.